# Cannot get a value from API

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, api, polygon

I have an issue with an API call from polygon.io.
I am using their free API which gives me information on stock tickers.

I am using an API that provides me a response when called.
From the response, I need to get response > data > results > "c" value, in this case, **1014.97**

So far the best I could do is:
`console.log(response.data.results)`

which gives:

```
  Array [
  Object {
    "T": "TSLA",
    "c": 1014.97,
    "h": 1090.5753,
    "l": 1000.21,
    "n": 1043576,
    "o": 1084.79,
    "t": 1638565200000,
    "v": 30773995,
    "vw": 1028.7486,
  },
```

**Please tell me how I can get the "c" value?**

Here is the full **response** data:

`console.log(response)`

This, in VS-Code>Terminal shows:

```
Object {
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "baseURL": "https://api.polygon.io/",
    "data": undefined,
    "headers": Object {
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "get",
    "params": Object {
      "apiKey": "Gp5IgTvT4fPbfhINPpOk7iBIUDjOTRc9",
    },
    "timeout": 5000,
    "transformRequest": Array [
      [Function transformRequest],
    ],
    "transformResponse": Array [
      [Function transformResponse],
    ],
    "transitional": Object {
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
    },
    "url": "v2/aggs/ticker/MSFT/prev",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  },
  "data": Object {
    "adjusted": true,
    "count": 1,
    "queryCount": 1,
    "request_id": "6a2a6c28efc5fcf9e4b1f295f845bf91",
    "results": Array [
      Object {
         "T": "TSLA",
         "c": 1014.97,
         "h": 1090.5753,
         "l": 1000.21,
         "n": 1043576,
         "o": 1084.79,
         "t": 1638565200000,
         "v": 30773995,
        "vw": 1028.7486,
      },
    ],
    "resultsCount": 1,
    "status": "OK",
    "ticker": "MSFT",
  },
  "duration": 406,
  "headers": Object {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "date": "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 21:37:55 GMT",
    "server": "nginx/1.19.2",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x-request-id": "6a2a6c28efc5fcf9e4b1f295f845bf91",
  },
  "ok": true,
  "originalError": null,
  "problem": null,
  "status": 200,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results is an array of dictionary Object. The dictionary Object containing "c" value is the first elements of the array.
So, you can get it like this

```
response.data.results[0].c
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "results" is an array with a dictionary inside you can reference the close value with response.data.results['c'].

Comment: i tried your method: `console.log(response.data.results['c'])` which results in **undefined**. @Achraf 's method worked. Thanks though :)